# Find time spent in a day along with work break taken

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am in a situation where I need to find-out total time spent in office for some internal application.

I have sample data like this:

```
Id  EmployeeId  ScanDateTime    Status
 7  87008   2018-08-02 16:03:00.227 1
 8  87008   2018-08-02 16:06:17.277 2
 9  87008   2018-08-02 16:10:37.107 3
 10 87008   2018-08-02 16:20:17.277 2
 11 87008   2018-08-02 16:30:37.107 3
12  87008   2018-08-02 20:06:00.000 4
```

Here Status have different meanings:

1- Start
2- Pause
3- Resume
4- End

Means Employees start their work at ScanDateTime when status is 1. They can go for break(status 2) and come back and resume their work(Status 3) and with status 4 means they are ending their job. 
Note: There could be multiple breaks during work hours.

Expected Output:

```
EmployeeId  StartTime                 EndTime                  BreakInMins 
87008       2018-08-02 16:03:00.227   2018-08-02 20:06:00.000   14
```

I have tried to follow some example to calculate the expected result set but not helping.

I could not find any such example where this similar example available.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this. Handles multiple breaks/employees and cases, when break is still in progress or session is not finished

```
select
     [EmployeeId]   =   [s].[EmployeeId]
    ,[StartTime]    =   [s].[ScanDateTime]
    ,[EndTime]      =   [et].[ScanDateTime]
    ,[BreakInMins]  =   [b].[BreakInMins]
from
    [Scans] as  [s] --  here is your table
outer apply
    (      
        select top 1 [ScanDateTime], [Id] from [Scans] where [Id] > [s].[Id] and [EmployeeId] = [s].[EmployeeId] and [Status] = 4 order by [ScanDateTime] asc
    )       as  [et]
outer apply
    (
        select
              [BreakInMins] = sum(isnull([r].[mins], datediff(mi, [sp].[ScanDateTime], getdate())))
        from
            [Scans] as [sp]
        outer apply
            (
                select top 1 [mins] = datediff(mi, [sp].[ScanDateTime], [ScanDateTime]) from [Scans] where [Id] > [sp].[Id] and [EmployeeId] = [sp].[EmployeeId] and [Status] IN (3, 4) order by [ScanDateTime] asc
            ) as [r]
        where
                [sp].[id] > [s].[id] and [sp].[id] < isnull([et].[id], [id] + 1)
            and [sp].[EmployeeId] = [s].[EmployeeId]
            and [sp].[Status] = 2

    )       as  [b]    
where
        [Status] = 1;
```

Here is test-friendly script: [script](https://pastebin.com/g58zAqTt)

Comment: I have seen your query too, its calculating break-mins incorrectly.

Comment: My query returns 14 mins, as expected in your question. If you give me some hints  about the potential bug, I'l fix it ;)

Comment: Uff, I fixed bug in the post, but pastebin content still has bug... Here is new testing code, please try: https://pastebin.com/g58zAqTt

Comment: Another bug fixed: when session ended without previous state as "resumed"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177726/discussion-between-error-handler-and-juozas).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. 
make a `row_number` in `CTE` by `Status`, because we need to know which Pause  time correspond which Resume time. then `self join` in the `CTE` by `EmployeeId`

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   Id  INT,
   EmployeeId INT,
   ScanDateTime DATETIME,
  Status INT
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES (7 ,87008 ,'2018-08-02 16:03:00.227',1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (8 ,87008 ,'2018-08-02 16:06:17.277',2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (9 ,87008 ,'2018-08-02 16:10:37.107',3);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (10,87008 ,'2018-08-02 16:20:17.277',2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (11,87008 ,'2018-08-02 16:30:37.107',3);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (12,87008 ,'2018-08-02 20:06:00.000',4);
```

**Query 1**:

```
;with cte as(
  SELECT *,
         MIN(ScanDateTime) over(partition by EmployeeId order by EmployeeId) StartTime,
         MAX(ScanDateTime) over(partition by EmployeeId order by EmployeeId) EndTime,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Status order by id) rn
  FROM t
)
select t1.EmployeeId,
       t1.StartTime,
       t1.EndTime,
       SUM(datediff(minute,t1.ScanDateTime,t2.ScanDateTime)) BreakInMins 
from 
cte t1 
inner join cte t2
on t1.rn =t2.rn and t1.Status = 2 and t2.Status = 3 and t1.EmployeeId = t2.EmployeeId
group by t1.EmployeeId,
       t1.StartTime,
       t1.EndTime
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9dda3/1/0)**:

```
| EmployeeId |            StartTime |                  EndTime | BreakInMins |
|------------|----------------------|--------------------------|-------------|
|      87008 | 2018-08-02T20:06:00Z | 2018-08-02T16:03:00.227Z |          14 |
```

**EDIT**

you can try this query if there are different day in your data. just group by the `date`.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   Id  INT,
   EmployeeId INT,
   ScanDateTime DATETIME,
  Status INT
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES (7 ,87008 ,'2018-08-02 16:03:00.227',1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (8 ,87008 ,'2018-08-02 16:06:17.277',2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (9 ,87008 ,'2018-08-02 16:10:37.107',3);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (10,87008 ,'2018-08-02 16:20:17.277',2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (11,87008 ,'2018-08-02 16:30:37.107',3);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (12,87008 ,'2018-08-02 20:06:00.000',4);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (27 ,87008 ,'2018-08-03 16:03:00.227',1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (28 ,87008 ,'2018-08-03 16:06:17.277',2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (29 ,87008 ,'2018-08-03 16:11:37.107',3);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (210,87008 ,'2018-08-03 16:20:17.277',2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (211,87008 ,'2018-08-03 16:30:37.107',3);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (212,87008 ,'2018-08-03 20:06:00.000',4);
```

**Query 1**:

```
;with cte as(
  SELECT EmployeeId,
         MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 1 then ScanDateTime end) StartTime,
         MIN(CASE WHEN Status = 4 then ScanDateTime end) EndTime,
         CAST(ScanDateTime as date) dt
  FROM t
  GROUP BY EmployeeId,CAST(ScanDateTime as date)
)
,cte2 as(
  SELECT t2.*,
         Row_number() over(partition by t2.EmployeeId,t2.Status order by Id) rn,
         t1.StartTime,
         t1.EndTime,
         t1.dt
  FROM cte t1 
  INNER JOIN T t2 ON t1.EmployeeId = t2.EmployeeId and Status in (2,3) and t1.dt =  CAST(t2.ScanDateTime as date)
)
select t1.EmployeeId,
       t1.StartTime,
       t1.EndTime,
       SUM(datediff(minute,t1.ScanDateTime,t2.ScanDateTime)) BreakInMins 
from cte2 t1 
inner join cte2 t2 on 
  t1.rn = t2.rn 
and 
  t1.EmployeeId = t2.EmployeeId
and t1.Status = 2 and t2.Status =3
group by t1.EmployeeId,
       t1.StartTime,
       t1.EndTime
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9dda3/1/0)**:

```
| EmployeeId |                StartTime |              EndTime | BreakInMins |
|------------|--------------------------|----------------------|-------------|
|      87008 | 2018-08-02T16:03:00.227Z | 2018-08-02T20:06:00Z |          14 |
|      87008 | 2018-08-03T16:03:00.227Z | 2018-08-03T20:06:00Z |          15 |
```

Comment: A small issue in your query but almost solved my problem. I liked the way query is written. Minor issue is that startTime and EndTime got swapped in your query.

Comment: @error_handler: frustrated with method you accepting right answer. 
Current solution has multiple issues: 1. When session is not finished, resume date is wrongly displayed as finish date. 2 when session paused, and still we are in break, break mins are calculated wrongly. 3 critical bug: when you have two finished sessions of same employee, ONE session with sum of minutes displayed instead of two. And, some other issues.

Comment: Hey @Juozas, don't frustrate. But at the moment the selected answer solved my problem that is why I accepted it as a correct answer. Sorry buddy. But I liked the way you point out the flows in the calculation. That flow is in the process, not here in the query. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @error_handler just keep in mind: by using 'right' answer you always have ONE session of employee as summary record. For example, employee was at job full month, every day. Daily from 8:00 to 17:00. By using this, you will have ONE session record for full month. But you had ~30 sessions per month, right? So, be careful.  And other bugs I mentioned before.

Comment: Hey  @Juozas, you are right, let me test this query with some more data. I will update you if I find some other issue.

Comment: Hey yes, it wont work for multiple days. I removed it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

i consider multiple breaks per day of employee you can check below i also provided fiddle link

```
select t1.*,t5.breakmins from
(
  select EmployeeId,min(StartTime) as StartTime,max(EndTime) as EndTime from 
(
  select EmployeeId,(case when status=1 then ScanDateTime end) as StartTime,
(case when status=4 then ScanDateTime end) as EndTime,
case when status=3 then ScanDateTime end as ResumeWork,
             case when status=2 then ScanDateTime end as pauseTime
    from emp

    ) as t group by EmployeeId
  )  t1
inner join
(
select EmployeeId, convert(date,ResumeWork) as day ,
 sum(case when status=2 then datediff(minute,ResumeWork,res)  end ) as breakmins from
(
select EmployeeId,ResumeWork,status ,
lag(ResumeWork) over(PARTITION BY EmployeeId order by ResumeWork desc) as res from 
(
 select * from 
(
select EmployeeId, case when status=3 then ScanDateTime end as ResumeWork,status from emp
) as t1 where ResumeWork is not null


    union all 
    select * from 
(
    select EmployeeId,case when status=2 then ScanDateTime end as pauseTime,status from emp
  ) as t2 where pauseTime is not null
 )  as t3 group by EmployeeId,ResumeWork,status
  ) t4 group by EmployeeId, convert(date,ResumeWork)
  )t5 on t1.EmployeeId=t5.EmployeeId
  and  convert(date,t1.StartTime)=t5.day


EmployeeId     StartTime                  EndTime          breakmins
87008   2018-08-02T16:03:00.227Z    2018-08-02T20:06:00Z    12
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ae60f/6

Comment: Thanks @Zaynul for answering. Your answer works okay but I am not a big fan of lots of sub-queries & joins. Still I liked the way you understood the problem accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6fe11/3

```
   select id,min(case when status=1 then stattime end) as starttime,
min(case when status=4 then stattime end) as endtime,
sum(case when status=2 then minute end) as breakinmin
from
(
select id,stattime,status,
DATEdiff(minute,stattime,lead(stattime,1,NULL) 
         over (partition by id ORDER BY stattime)) as minute
    from ForgeRock)a
    group by id

id      starttime                   endtime                 breakinmin
87008   2018-08-02T16:03:00.227Z    2018-08-02T20:06:00Z    14
```

Comment: Hey, this isn't working. It wont calculate WorkBreakInMins. It is generating always null.

Comment: check now, modify query and also given sqlfiddle link

Comment: Even it will fail when their are multiple breaks are taken as you are taking min() out of Pause or Resume types.

Comment: do you have any breakid there

Comment: Not exactly, I am putting some more values in my question sample imput and expected output.

Comment: Added few more items in sample input and updated expected output. Check updated question.

Comment: modified the query, check pls