# Calculate total running time and pause time

Tags: sql

Calculate total running time and pause time

[image]

I have table as shown in attached image.

Transaction Status meaning : 3= start, 6= pause, 5=stop

I need running time & pause time for batch run template id

Notes :

1. Transaction can be paused and resumed multiple times as shown in image
2. STOP can occure only once and can occur after the pause transaction or start transaction
3. if a transaction started but not paused and stopped system should pick up the current date to calculate

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: Most people here want sample data as formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: yeh, what @jarlh said: [don't post images of data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481)

Comment: @DeepakGoyal . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are actually using, which is presumably either SQL Server or Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer to very same problem. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760743/find-time-spent-in-a-day-along-with-work-break-taken/51762742#51762742), and slightly modify by your needs :)

Comment: Thanks @Juozas .. this looks helpful :)